# c++ polymorphic method defined in derived class matches type that should match to the parent

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm experimenting with this code

```
class Base
{
public:
virtual void foo(int) {
// void foo(int) {
    cout << "int" << endl;
}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
void foo(double) {
    cout << "double" << endl;
}
};

int main()
{
    Base* p = new Derived;
    p->foo(2.1);
    
    Derived d;
    d.foo(2);  // why isn't this double?
    
    return 0;
}
```

It's also available in online editor here https://onlinegdb.com/s8NwhfG_Yy

I'm getting

```
int
double
```

I don't understand why d.foo(2) calls the double version. Since Derived inherits the int method and has its own double method, wouldn't polymorphism dictate that 2 be matched to the parent? Thanks.

Comment: remember to mark overrides with the `override` keyword so that the compiler raises an error when you aren't actually overriding anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism as in calling virtual methods is orthogonal to symbol and overload resolution. The former happens run-time, the rest at compile-time.

`object->foo()` **always resolves the symbol at compile-time** - member variable with overloaded `operator()` or a method. `virtual` only delays selecting "the body" of the method. The signature is always fixed, including the return value of course. Otherwise the type system would break. This is one of the reasons why there cannot be virtual function templates.

What you are actually experiencing is name hiding and overload resolution.

For `Base* p; p->foo(2.1)`, the list of possible symbol candidates is only `Base::foo(int)`. The compiler cannot know that `p` points to `Derived` (in general) because the choice must be done at compile time. Since `int` is implicitly convertible to `double`, `foo(int)` is chosen. Because the method is virtual, if `Derived` were to provide its own `foo(int) override`, it would have been called instead of `Base::foo(int)` at run-time.

For `Derived*d; d->foo(2)`, the compiler first looks for symbol `foo` in `Derived`. Since there is `foo(double)` which is valid as `foo(2)`, it is chosen. If there was no valid candidate, only then the compiler would look into base classes. If there was `Derived::foo(int)`, possibly virtual, the compiler would choose this instead because it is a better match.

You can disable the name hiding by writing

```
class Derived: public Base{
    using Base::foo;
};
```

It injects all `Base::foo` methods into `Derived` scope. After this, `Base::foo(int)` (now really `Derived::foo(int)`) is chosen as the better match.

Answer (score 1):

Read [Overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). The answer is in **Details**:

> If any candidate function is a member function (static or non-static), but not a constructor, it is treated as if it has an extra parameter (implicit object parameter) which represents the object for which they are called and appears before the first of the actual parameters.

The selecting between the methods `void foo(int)` and `void foo(double)` is happening like between the functions `void foo(Base, int)` and `void foo(Derived, double)`. The second function while calling `d.foo(2)` is ranked higher.

If you add `using Base::foo;` in `Derived`, the resolution will be performed between three functions `void foo(Base, int)`, `void foo(Derived, int)` and `void foo(Derived, double)`, and `int` will be printed.